# search engine error

Tags: php, search-engine

I seam to be getting the problem in the code below. The problems that arise are

> "Notice: Undefined variable: i in C:\wamp\www\search\search.php on
>   line 21"

and

> "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\wamp\www\search\search.php on line 34".

Line 21 is `$i++;`

Line 34 is `$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query)`

```
<body>
    <h2>Search Engine</h2>
    <form action='./search.php' method='get'>
        <input type='text' name='k' size='50' value='<?php echo $_GET['k'] ?>' />
        <input type='submit' value='Search'/>
    </form>
    <hr />
    <?php
    $k = $_GET['k'];
    $terms = explode(" ", $k);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

    foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;

        if($i == 1)
            $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        else
            $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }

    //connect
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
    mysql_select_db("search");

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($num_rows > 0){

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $keywords = $row['Keywords'];
            $link = $row['link'];

            echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>
            $description<br /><br />";
        }

    }
    else
        echo "No results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";

    //disconnect
    mysql_close();

    ?>
</body>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: **Warning**: You are outputting data from the URI directly into the page and are therefore vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error1:**
use of for loop:

```
foreach ($terms as $each)
{
    //....
}
```

or

```
for($i = 0; i < count($terms); i++)
{
    $each = $terms[i];
    //....
}
```

$i++ is useless in foreach

**Error2:**
[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) will fail and return FALSE if the user does not have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query. 
so here is a sample code to fix it:

```
$num_rows = 0;
if($query){
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just incrementing the variable which is not assigned yet

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;

        if($i == 1)
            $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        else
            $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }
```

or else simply do

```
foreach ($terms as $each){
        $selects[] = "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";

}
$query .= implode(" OR ",$selects);
```

i think this will be the reason for warning `mysql_num_rows()` too